# Where is 'pyximport'?

Tags: python-2.7, cython

I have some (not so) old code in which I use [`pyximport`](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#pyximport), but the code fails right at

```
import pyximport; pyximport.install()
```

with

> ImportError: No module named pyximport

I've made a few changes to my system since I last ran this code, so perhaps it was removed or not migrated; but I can't find this package anywhere and

```
pip search pyximport
```

yields no results.

What happened to `pyximport`? Where can I find it and, failing that, what should I use instead?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

pyximport is a part of cython.

```
$ pip install cython
```

You can find the description of it [here](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html#compiling-with-pyximport). In short, pyximport provides an import hook which allows you to import cython files (and compile them) as though they were python.

Comment: I have Cython (0.23.4), so I wonder why `pyximport` is not found.

Comment: pyximport appears to work under cython latest (0.23.4)

Comment: Any thoughts on what could be going on then? If I `pip install -U --force-reinstall Cython` I still get a module not found error from `import pyximport`.

Comment: Is your copy of pip writing to the correct virtual environment / condo install? (Can you see it in site-packages)

Comment: Also - do you have an appropriate compiler on your system path? This one is doubtful, but you'll need to double check it going forward

Comment: Also, on Linux, do you have the python headers installed?

Comment: Cython right there in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. In fact `pyximport` is right there too.

Comment: Would the absence of headers give a "no module named" error?